# Adding SearchView in Fragment

Tags: android, xamarin, searchview

Trying to include a searchview in actionbar. For this, I have done the following:

Created MenuSearch.xml in the menu folder as given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:actionViewClass="Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Search"/>

</menu>
```

Included the method OnCreateOptionsMenu in the fragment:

```
public override void OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        inflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.MenuSearch, menu);
        base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        var searchManager = (SearchManager) this.Activity.GetSystemService(Context.SearchService);
        searchView = (SearchView) (menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.action_search).ActionView);
        searchView.SetSearchableInfo(searchManager.GetSearchableInfo(Activity.ComponentName));

    }
```

And I have set `HasOptionsMenu = true;` in oncreate of the fragment.

With the code above, I get null pointer in the line `searchView.SetSearchableInfo...` . Not sure why this happens, though everything seem to be correct and in place.

Based on some suggestions for resolving similar issue, I have also tried out the below option for searchview.

```
        var item = menu.FindItem (Resource.Id.action_search);
        var searchItem = MenuItemCompat.GetActionView(item);
        searchView = searchItem.JavaCast<Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView>();
        searchView.SetSearchableInfo(searchManager.GetSearchableInfo(Activity.ComponentName));
```

But again, I get searchView as null.

Now that I have tried the possible options, I am clueless as to why searchview becomes null.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Change your MenuSearch.xml to

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
            android:title="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
            app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
             />
    </menu>
```

And in your fragment, add   `searchView.setOnQueryTextListener`

```
    @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
            menu.clear();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_option_menu, menu);
            MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
            SearchView searchView = new SearchView(((MainActivity) mContext).getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
           // MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(item, //MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW | //MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
           //  MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, searchView);
           // These lines are deprecated in API 26 use instead
 item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
        item.setActionView(searchView);
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    return false;
                }
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
            searchView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                              @Override
                                              public void onClick(View v) {

                                              }
                                          }
            );
        }
```

Comment: getting nullPointerException on          SearchView searchView = new SearchView(((MainActivity) mContext).getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());

Comment: Your application style is probably not supporting actionbars. Please check whether your style does that.

Comment: `MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(item, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW | MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
        MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, searchView);` This two lines are deprecated please update answer......

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Answer updated for 2018. Sorry for Kotlin, if you're using Java.

Your xml menu resource (search_menu.xml for example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        />
</menu>
```

Build-up code:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater?) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    menu.clear()
    inflater?.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu)
    val searchView = SearchView((context as MainActivity).supportActionBar?.themedContext ?: context)
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).apply {
        setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW or MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM)
        actionView = searchView
    }

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
            return false
        }
    })
    searchView.setOnClickListener {view ->  }
}
```

You'll probably also need to put this line in `onCreate()` (worked for my fragment) to get this all to appear:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true)
```

Answer (score 3):

For late 2018 and for apis >= `26` compatible (deprecation warnings) and a properly formatted answer:

The `menu.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="Search_change_me_with_proper_id"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

Java code inside the `ActivityFragment`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true); // Add this!
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_app, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_add_app, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search_menu_add_app);
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // Here is where we are going to implement the filter logic
            return true;
        }

    });
}
```

OR as a **second option** you let the `ActivityFragment` implement `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` and then use the menu search:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true); // Add this! (as above)
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_app, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_add_app, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search_menu_add_app);
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this); // Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
    // Here is where we are going to implement the filter logic
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i solved this issue i wants to share my answer for searchView NullPointerException

we need to remove below method from Main Activity

```
      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
          int id = item.getItemId();  
          return true;
```

and use inside fragment in OnActivityCreated  `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`
and Override methods

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
         inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       // handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:

     //       onCall();   //your logic

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your **search_options_menu.xml** should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
         />
</menu>
```

Override **onCreateOptionMenu** method in your fragment `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` inside **onCreate()** on your fragment.

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
       menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_option_menu, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
                SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
        MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(item, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW | MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
        MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, searchView);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    //Do search code here
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
search_view.setOnQueryTextListener(object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(query: String?): Boolean {
                adapter.filter.filter(query)
                return true
            }
        })
```

And don't add the intent filter for your activity in Manifest file.

Answer (score -1):

In my fragment's onCreateOptionsMenu the code

```
SearchManager searchManager =
        (SearchManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
SearchableInfo searchableInfo =
        searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName());
searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
searchView.setSearchableInfo( searchableInfo);
```

produced following error message:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.setSearchableInfo  (android.app.SearchableInfo)' on a null object reference

After i changed in menu.xml android:actionViewClass to app:actionViewClass the problem did not occur again.
menu.xml :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:context="...">
<item
android:id="@+id/menu_search"
android:title="@string/menu_search"
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom">
```